# creating a duplicate of absolute function in python

Tags: python

I am trying to duplicate the *abs* function in python. My code is close I think but doesn't give error for non-compatible input types. It also outputs the absolute value + 0j. So what should I edit?

```
def abc(x):
    if isinstance(x, complex):
        y = (x.real**2 - (x - x.real)**2)**0.5
    elif x>=0:
        y = x
    else:
        y = -x
    return y
```

It outputs the absolute value + 0j. Anyway to remove that?

Comment: The source code of the original is freely available ...

Comment: *Why* are you trying to duplicate the abs function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.real` attribute appears to be defined for `int` and `float`, so you can simply `return y.real` in the last line.

It's probably cleaner to use `x.imag` instead of `x - x.real` though, which will sidestep the issue entirely.

Comment: Technically, absolute of a list input gives type error while your approach gives attribute error. But still close enough, I guess

Comment: @SurajRam That really just goes back to the question in the comments, which is: why do you need this? You can keep hacking things together until you exactly replicate the behavior of `abs()`, but why bother when you can just use `abs()`?

Comment: I am just learning python and my tutor asked me to try this as practice

Answer (score 0):

Your computation of the imaginary part for complex types gives you a complex number which is not what you want. You want a real number, so the result is real.

Change:

```
y = (x.real**2 - (x - x.real)**2)**0.5
```

To:

```
y = (x.real**2 + x.imag**2)**0.5
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> x = 4 + 6j
>>> abs(x)
7.211102550927978
>>> (x.real**2 - (x - x.real)**2)**0.5 # your approach
(7.211102550927978+0j)                 # notice the 0j
>>> (x.real**2 + x.imag**2)**0.5
7.211102550927978
```